# passing an index value to a javascript namespaced array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

As part of a joomla site, I have a fair number (>20) of quite long arrays (~50 elements) of English sentences located in several files. These arrays are to be accessed by jquery click events which will display the sentences as examples of English word use.The click event functionality which generates the array indices for individual sentences is working. I want to namespace the arrays using a module pattern. According to
http://www.2ality.com/2011/04/modules-and-namespaces-in-javascript.html, module definitions can be spread over several locations. This would be very useful from the point of view of module scalability.  I've modified a module from the above article, thus:

```
var namespace = function() {
     var index = 2;    // for example
     var arr = ["the boy is going home",
                "You and I are friends",
                "He has a book of mine"]; 
    return {
        get values() {
            return arr[index];
        }
    };
}();
console.log(namespace.values);
```

This works as far as it goes. However, I want to pass an array index to the module and have it return the corresponding text. How can this be done?

Comment: Do you mean you want to namespace.values(index) ?

Comment: `return {values: function(index) {
            return arr[index];
        } }` And call it with `console.log(namespace.values(*index*));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var namespace = function() {
     var arr = ["the boy is going home",
                "You and I are friends",
                "He has a book of mine"]; 
    return {
        values: function(index) {
            return arr[index];
        }
    };
}();
console.log(namespace.values(1));
```

So when the `IIFE` returns the objet properties for `namespace`, we make `values` a function (`method`) and pass in the `index`. Once the IIFE executes you could think of it like this;

```
var namespace =  {
    values: function(index) {
        return arr[index];
    }
}
```

but with the initialised `arr` array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
namespace = function() {
     this.index = 2;    // for example
     this.arr = ["the boy is going home",
                "You and I are friends",
                "He has a book of mine"]; 
};
namespace.prototype.getValueAt = function(index){
   return this.arr[index];
};
console.log(namespace.getValueAt(0));
```

Comment: Thanks to all, I appreciate your help @Nick M your explanation was very helpful. Cheers